# 2D platform unable to get to the next level

Tags: javascript, godot

I made a 2D platformer game in Godot and can't program the game to proceed to next level. The player just phases through the trophy, which should take the player to the next level, without proceeding.

```js
extends Area2D

@export var target_level : PackedScene

func _on_body_entered(body):
    if (body.name == "CharacterBody2D"):
        get_tree().change_scene_to_packed(target_level)
```

I have tried change the code but nothing happen it keep phasing through the throphy [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DALhW.png) [and here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOB9s.png)

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Do you reach the on body entered function, when hitting the trophy? if so, is the name of your body really CharacterBody2D? Is the target_level variable actually set to another scene? Try to be a bit more clear and give us more informations